# Is it possible to explore to elements nested more than 64 deep with the IE11 DOM Explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a giant monstrosity of an HTML document I'm working with that has some very deeply-nested content. I would like to use the F12 Developer Tools in IE11 to examine some of the deepest content. However, it seems I am unable to expand the tree to a depth of more than 64. You can see this for yourself if you stick the HTML below into an html file and open it with IE11.

```
<html><body><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><span>This is at depth 65</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

The highlighted div in the image below is the parent of the `<span>`, and cannot be expanded, though you can right-click and edit as HTML. (But the actual HTML I want to explore is nested to a depth of around 100, and I don't want to pick through the remaining 30+ layers by hand.)

[image]

Is there a setting or something that will let me explore to elements nested more than 64 deep?

I am using Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18500.

Comment: That’s apparently an IE bug. Btw, there is most likely something wrong with your page if it has such deep nesting.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Welcome to Enterprise Software™! Do you have a link or something indicating that this is a known bug?

Comment: There is a [bug ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9038134/) in the Microsoft’s bug tracker, but it’s closed on the ground that they don’t accept IE bugs anymore after Edge release. Btw, what prevents you from using developer tools of a _different_ browser?

Comment: @MaratTanalin I'd love to use Chrome's dev tools (which handle deep nesting fine), but our Enterprise Software™ does not reliably run on browsers other than IE. That bug ticket pretty much answers my question ("no, it's not possible"), if you want to post it as an answer.

Comment: In the browser click on the element. then in the console tab of dev tools execute....
console.dir(document.activeElement)

Answer (score 0):

Per comment from [Marat Tanalin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211187/marat-tanalin):

> There is a [bug ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9038134/) in the Microsoft’s bug tracker, but it’s closed on the ground that they don’t accept IE bugs anymore after Edge release.

So the answer to my question is "no". Oh well.